# Gravity on par with the other forces

Tags: gravity, interactions

Gravity is said to be the weakest of the fundamental interactions, of which the other three, the electromagnetic and the strong/weak nuclear forces, are the more powerful.
My question is simply, **what could we expect the universe to *do* if gravity were on par with the other forces?** That is, if gravity were 'average', comparably, how might we expect matter and energy to behave fundamentally?
My instantaneous guess would be that everything becomes a black hole.
This question pseudoscientific. If it can't be answered due to the constraints of this exchange, then I may instead ask for a resource to approach an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If gravity were even a small bit stronger than it is, the universe would soon collapse after the big bang back into a singularity. There would be no time for galaxies to form and perhaps no time either for stars to form and process hydrogen into heavier elements.

Comment: I don't want to add anything to the question to disqualify your answer, but I just mean to ask, what if the initial inflation were also increased to compensate the excessive gravitational forces, such that particles may precipitate from the big bang and we may observe their interactions?

Comment: I have no idea what would happen then.

Comment: Haha, okay fair enough